# If $b:[0,T]\times ℝ→ℝ$ is Borel measurable and $(X_t)_{t\in[0,\:T]}$ is continuous and adapted, then $t\mapsto b(t,X_t)$ is progressively measurable

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let

- $T>0$
- $b:[0,T]\times\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be $\mathcal
     B([0,T])\otimes\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$-measurable and
  $$|b(t,x)-b(t,y)\le L|x-y|\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,T]\text{ and
     }x,y\in\mathbb R$$ for some $L\ge 0$
- $(X_t)_{t\in[0,\:T]}$ be a real-valued $\mathcal F$-adapted continuous stochastic process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$

> Can we show that $$\varphi_t:=b(t,X_t)\;\;\;\text{for }t\in[0,T]$$ is $\mathcal F$-progressively measurable?

It's clear that $X$ itself is $\mathcal F$-progressively measurable. So, it should be easy to conclude the claim. How can we argue?

Comment: @oxbadfood : It appears to me as an application of composition argument of measurable functions (try to prove first that $u : (s,\omega) \to (s,X_s(\omega))$ from space $([0,t]\times \Omega)$ to space $([0,t]\times \mathbb R)$ , with sigma-algebras $\mathcal
   B([0,t])\otimes\mathcal {F_t} $ to $\mathcal
   B([0,t])\otimes\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ is measurable (if true for every $t \in [0,T]$ then $\phi \circ u (s,\omega)$ is progressively measurable. Best regards